# Angular 4 and ClojureScript background information

Tags: angular, clojure, server, clojurescript

I need some information about resource management of Angular4 and ClojureScript. I don't have any knowledge about this and also can't find anything. Maybe I just search for the wrong keywords.

What I want to know is, if there is a cap of the simultaneous users of a web page using just Angular 4 or ClojureScript. Or does all this just depend on the server? How is the resource management on the server? I heared something, that Clojure for example takes everything, what it can get. Is this right?

Background for this information is, we want to create a new simple web page, which provides some data from a database. It will be just 1 site. But alot simultaneous users will visit this page, and the page should be accessible all the time.

Sorry for my bad english. Hope you could help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Clojure is not ClojureScript.  So forget the stuff about "Clojure taking everything" (whatever that may mean).  ClojureScript is just Clojure code compiled into JavaScript.  And Angular is a JavaScript framework.  So the two are not really comparable.  If you want to know how "efficient" Angular code, or ClojureScript code is, it depends on what you do with it.  Just like in every framework or any language on any platform, you can write good and bad code, or efficient and inefficient code.

In short: regarding the number of simultaneous users a site can handle, it does not really depend on the framework used, but on what is being shown on the site an what algorithms and datastructures behind it are used.

Having experience with both Angular en ClojureScript, Angular is great if you want to work in pure JavaScript, but I can highly recommend ClojureScript combined with [Re-Frame](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame)!  It's very efficient IMO, but to be honest, it requires some advanced knowledge of ClojureScript and React.js.

Comment: thank you very much for the fast reply and to clarify this for me. maybe I understood something wrong at the beginning. but I think, this will make the decition much easier for us. since I got alot knowledge with angular and almost none with clojue(Script) we will use Angular for the web page.